# SQL query to get current and last year sales

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table Sales:

```
Date        Store   Sales
1/1/2015    St01    12123
1/1/2015    St02    3123
1/1/2016    St01    4213
1/1/2016    St03    2134
```

When I try to self join to get this year and last year sales the closed store is not showing up.
The result should be like this:

```
Date        Store   This year Sales   Last Year Sales
1/1/2016    St01    4213              1212
1/1/2016    St02    0                 3123
1/1/2016    St03    2134              0
```

My query as follows:

```
SELECT CY.DATE, 
       CY.store cy.Sales, 
       LY.sales 
FROM   sales CY, 
       sales LY 
WHERE  CY.store(+) = LY.store(+) 
       AND LY.DATE = CY.DATE - 365
```

Comment: do you even need that first column "Date" there in yoru results?

Comment: Yes, I will need it for the weekly and monthly sales too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I want the query to return day by day sales I used [**MT0**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509264/mt0) answer and added the dates, this way I can get the data for all year days.

```
WITH AllYear AS
 (select to_date('2016-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') + level - 1 AS dobs
    from dual
  connect by level <= 366)

SELECT dobs AS "DATE",
       Store,
       nvl(SUM(CASE
                 WHEN t.Date = dobs THEN
                  t.sales
               END),
           0) AS "This Year Sales",
       nvl(SUM(CASE
                 WHEN t.Date = dobs-365 THEN
                  t.sales
               END),
           0) AS "Last Year Sales"
  FROM Sales t,AllYear
 where dobs='01-Jan-2016'
 GROUP BY Store
 ORDER BY Store;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called Pivoting Table. Although Oracle has specific clauses to do it, you can use just plain and pure SQL to do so, like this:

```
SELECT store, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Extract(year FROM DATE) = Extract(year FROM SYSDATE) THEN 
             sales 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS "This year Sales", 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Extract(year FROM DATE) = Extract(year FROM SYSDATE) - 1 THEN 
             sales 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS "Last year Sales" 
FROM   sales 
WHERE  Extract(year FROM DATE) >= Extract(year FROM SYSDATE) - 1 
GROUP  BY store 
ORDER  BY store
```

It would show:

```
Store    This year Sales    Last year Sales
St01     4213               12123
St02     0                  3123
St03     2134               0
```

Note that makes no sense to have to column `date` as the first column. You couldn't group by it to show the output you want.

See the equivalent of this query here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7662d8/6

Comment: Thank you for a very good answer, So this will sum all year sales but what if I want to do it week by week and month by month?

Comment: Then you would have to break your dates into these periods. The `extract` can do it easily by month. For the week it would be a bit more complicated since `extract` to it, you would have to use a combination like `to_number(to_char(to_date('01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW'))` this returns the week number, then you could group by it, But you would have to have periods, right now you only have dates. You should ask a new question for this. It is entirely different. Please chose the answer that better fit your question and mark it as accepted. It will help others.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE sales ( "DATE", Store, Sales ) AS
SELECT DATE '2015-01-01', 'St01', 12123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2015-01-01', 'St02',  3123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-01-01', 'St01',  4213 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-01-01', 'St03',  2134 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YY' ) AS "DATE",
       Store,
       SUM( CASE WHEN "DATE" = TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YY' )
                 THEN sales END )
         AS "This year sales",
       SUM( CASE WHEN "DATE" = ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YY' ), -12 )
                 THEN sales END )
         AS "Last year sales"
FROM   sales
GROUP BY store
ORDER BY store;
```

**Output**:

```
DATE                STORE This year sales Last year sales
------------------- ----- --------------- ---------------
2016-01-01 00:00:00 St01             4213           12123 
2016-01-01 00:00:00 St02                             3123 
2016-01-01 00:00:00 St03             2134
```

Answer (score -1):

The general solution is a **full outer join**, which includes all records from both joined tables.  I don't know the Oracle syntax, but in MS SQL Server it would be something like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CY.DATE, LY.DATE) as DATE, 
       ISNULL(CY.store, LY.store) as STORE,
       isnull(cy.Sales, 0), 
       isnull(LY.sales, 0) 
FROM   sales CY FULL OUTER JOIN sales LY 
    ON CY.store = LY.store
       AND (CY.DATE IS NULL OR 
            DATEPART(year, LY.DATE) = DATEPART(year, CY.DATE) - 1
```

`ISNULL(a, b)` gives `a` if `A IS NOT NULL`, else `b`. `DATEPART` extracts specified part of a date; I'm comparing a difference of exactly one year rather than 365 days, in case "last year" is a leap year/

Comment: This is not MS SQL, and it is also not a FULL, JOIN or anything join related. It is a Pivoting question.

Answer (score -2):

I only work with SQL Server. If anything is different, try to apply the same logic.

**Declaring a temporary table to test the query:**

```
DECLARE @Sales TABLE (
    [Date] DATE,
    Store NVARCHAR(10),
    Sales INT
)

INSERT INTO @Sales VALUES 
    ('1/1/2015','St01',12123),
    ('1/1/2015','St02',3123),
    ('1/1/2016','St01',4213),
    ('1/1/2016','St03',2134);

SELECT * FROM @Sales;
```

**The actual query:**

```
SELECT 
    CY_Date = CASE 
        WHEN CY.Date IS NULL THEN DATEADD(YEAR, 1, LY.Date)
        ELSE CY.Date
        END,
    LY_Date = CASE 
        WHEN LY.Date IS NULL THEN DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CY.Date)
        ELSE LY.Date
        END,
    Store = CASE 
        WHEN CY.Store IS NULL THEN LY.Store
        ELSE CY.Store
        END,
    ISNULL(CY.Sales, 0) AS CY_Sales,
    ISNULL(LY.Sales, 0) AS LY_Sales
FROM @Sales CY
FULL JOIN @Sales LY ON (CY.Store = LY.Store AND LY.Date = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CY.Date))
WHERE (CY.Date = '1/1/2016' OR CY.Date IS NULL) 
    AND (LY.Date = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, '1/1/2016') OR LY.Date IS NULL);
```

**Result:**

```
CY_Date     LY_Date     Store   CY_Sales    LY_Sales
2016-01-01  2015-01-01  St01    4213        12123
2016-01-01  2015-01-01  St03    2134        0
2016-01-01  2015-01-01  St02    0           3123
```

**How it works:**

- The FULL JOIN will will combine by the Store and the lines from the current and the year before.
- The WHERE clause will filter by the current date '1/1/2016'. The NULLs are allowed because sometimes you don't have lines for the current or for the last year.
- On the columns, CASES are used to create the dates if they are null (If the current date is null, get the last year + 1 year, and vice versa), to create the store if they are null and to place a zero instead of a null on the sales columns.

Comment: Your answer is for SQLServer not oracle. There is no dateadd function in oracle.

Comment: Use `add_months(CY.Date,12)` instead of DATEADD then.

Comment: Sorry, this is a oracle specific question. There are lots of things on your query that won't help at all the OP in fact can even confound him.  Also, no need at all for joining of full joining this since it is just a pivoting question.